# Connection failed. Please check your internet connection in android app

Tags: android, quickblox

We have integrated quickblox sdk in our android app for chatting. Sometimes the app performs very well without any issues. But at  other times the app doesn't login into the chat and returns **Connection failed. Please check your internet connection**

When we got this error we checked our connection and it was working absolutely fine. The user was able to login on the same phone using the same internet connection after sometime.

The stacktrace was:

```
Connection failed. Please check your internet connection.
at com.hoodoo.chat.ChatService$4.onError(ChatService.java:168)
at com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService$1.performInAsync(QBChatService.java:314)
at com.quickblox.chat.utils.ThreadTask.run(ThreadTask.java:18)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: facing the same error, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to log internet condition by android tools before making a request, as the presence of connection doesn't mean the presence of the internet.